# How do I style Section and ScrolledForm headers in Eclipse RAP?

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-rap

In Eclipse RAP most components can be styled through CSS e.g.:

```
Combo:hover {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
Combo-Button:hover {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

How can I style `Section` and `ScrolledForm` components? They seem to be linked to the `Shell-Titlebar` but what if I want to have a different `Shell` titlebar and `Section` header?

This CSS creates the following output:

```
Shell-Titlebar {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

[image: Section Header]

The style which manipulates the font color is the following (yes the `background-color`):

```
List-Item {
  /** this is for Section and Form heading font color */
  background-color: #4A4A4A;    
}
```